# Authentication failed in Git bash while cloning repository

Tags: git-bash

I tried changing username and tried setting it global but nothing is working.

git clone https://repository url
cloning into 'convert input'...
remote:HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://repository url'

Comment: Please help if anyone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I was trying to clone a repository via terminal and the problem was that I was using my github password instead of the [my personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens). It is a silly distraction, but I hope this answer will prevent others from doing the same thing.